# Как выранить отображение таблицы rtf файла в RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, richtextbox, rtf

Есть RTF файл, который содержит таблицу. Содержимое файла необходимо отобразить в RichTextBox.

Сложность в следующем: если таблица содержит чейки по одной строке, то всё корректно отображается. НО если табличка будет содержать по несколько строк, то RichTextBox будет думать, что это просто одна длинная строка и не будет правильно отображать содержимое, коверкая весь документ.

я слышал, что RTF содержит в себе теги. так вот если праавильно их отобазить, то можно по идее исправить ситуацию.

Что из себя представляют эти теги? И как исправить корректность отображения таблицы?

Comment: на входе точно RTF? Пробовали открывать такие файлы в WordPad? Если да, корректно ли он там отображается?

Comment: Открываете RTF как плоский текст (например, в Notepad++), ищете таблицу: каждая строка начинается с `\trowd`, заканчивается на `\row`. Смотрите, что не так. [ссылко](http://www.pindari.com/rtf3.html)